# .blend scenes are not showing texture in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, blender

I am new to Unity and Blender. I am getting a problem when importing `.blend` files into Unity: in Unity scenes the textures created in Blender are not showing.  But there are no problems with color. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please walk us through the steps to reproduce this problem. How have you set up your texture coordinates in Blender? What do the imported materials look like when you add the file to your Unity project?

Comment: I used Shading and UV wrapping in blender with base texture, Normal maps, height maps, etc and saved the blender file. After importing the project in blender the outcome was NO Material. (White) @DMGregory

Comment: Are your textures procedurally generated in Blender? Procedurally generated textures from Blender will not show up in Unity. If your textures are image files, you can just import them into your Unity project separately and assign them to materials in Unity.